# Power of an Affine Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In $\mathbb{R}$. Given an affine transformation matrix
$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}R&T \\ 0&1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

where $R$ is a full-rank $N \times N$ matrix and $T$ is a non-null $1 \times N$ vector, what is
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha} A^\alpha$$

I can compute this if $T$ is null (using eigenvalues) or if the eigenvalues of $R$ are either all magnitude less than 1 or all magnitude greater than 1 (using power series).

$A^\alpha$ can be computed (eg) as follows:
If $\alpha < 0$, $A^\alpha = (A^{-1})^\alpha$.
If $\alpha > 1$, $A^\alpha = A A^{\alpha-1}$.
If $\alpha > 1/2$, let $B^2 = A$, $A^\alpha = B A^{\alpha-1/2}$.
This last can be repeated ($C^2 = B$ for $\alpha > 1/4$, etc) to give the convergent series $\sum_n (0,1)_n A^{(2^{-n})}$, where $(0,1)_n$ is zero or one, depending on if the $n^\mathrm{th}$ binary "bit" is added. This method of construction does not lend itself easily to computing a derivative.

Comment: 1. There are sometimes no square roots to $A$, and sometimes many.  How do you choose $B$?  2. Why do you believe the series converges?  In what measure?

Comment: Both of your questions relate to my example of how one might compute $A^\alpha$. Although I could answer them, I am curious; how do these questions relate to a solution to the derivative question at hand?

Comment: On further thought, I suppose $R$ must be proper (ie, not an improper rotation). I am not sure if that is the same as $det(R) > 0$.

Comment: The reason my questions are relevant is that in order to define a derivative, (among other things) you need to take a limit as $\alpha\to 0$, so in particular you need $A^\alpha$ to be well-defined.

Comment: Let $B = \left(\begin{matrix}S&U\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$.
Then $S = E^-1 D^{1/2} E$ ($E$ are the eigenvectors of $R$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $R$.) and $U = (I+S)^{-1} T$. Choose the square roots of the $D$ elements to always have positive real part. Given that $S$ has positive-real-part eigenvalues, $I+S$ is always invertible.

Convergence is tougher. Not quite sure how to approach that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with affine transformations is that $R$ is almost always a rotation, which has an eigenvalue of 1, while the translation part always has an eigenvalue of 1. If the matrix is put into Jordan Normal Form, then defining $A^\alpha$ in a smooth way is trivial. If D are the non-unity eigenvalues, then
$$A^\alpha = P^-1 \left(\begin{matrix}D^\alpha&0\\0&F\end{matrix}\right) P$$
where $$F = \left(\begin{matrix}1&\alpha\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$